# If an ActiveX control running in IE calls other libraries, do those libraries need to implement IObjectSafety?

Tags: .net, activex, webbrowser-control

I have a .NET ActiveX control running in the browser (IE.) It calls other libraries (also passed through the site) to perform features such as logging, which requires writing to disk. Do these other libraries also need to implement IObjectSafety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Appears that only the publicly exposed assembly needs this.

It turned out after much debugging that the real problem I had was due to the ActiveX library not properly resolving .NET dependency paths when instantiated as an ActiveX using the class ID. I resolved this by adding the following to my ActiveX library's constructor, and it works fine now:

```
public YourActiveXLibrary()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(LoadInstallDependency);
}

private static Assembly LoadInstallDependency(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string installPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string dependencyPath = Path.Combine(installPath, new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll");
    return File.Exists(dependencyPath) ? Assembly.LoadFrom(dependencyPath) : null;
}
```